# Query is too slow and not using existing index

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple query that takes quite long to load (~ 20min.)

Here's my query plan: https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/RZm

And this is the query in question:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count,
    dd.country,
    COALESCE(dd.state, 'unknown'::character varying) AS state,
    COALESCE(dd.district, 'unknown'::character varying) AS district,
    dd.region,
    df.facilityname,
    dde.date,
    df.tenantid,
    ds.systemmanufacturer,
        CASE
            WHEN dd.country IS NULL OR dd.country::text = 'unknown'::text THEN false
            ELSE true
        END AS country_detected,
        CASE
            WHEN dd.state IS NULL OR dd.state::text = 'unknown'::text THEN false
            ELSE true
        END AS state_detected,
        CASE
            WHEN dd.district IS NULL OR dd.district::text = 'unknown'::text THEN false
            ELSE true
        END AS district_detected
   FROM fact_entriesexits fe
     JOIN dim_licenseplate dd ON dd.key = fe.licenseplatekey
     JOIN dim_facility df ON df.key = fe.facilitykey
     JOIN dim_date dde ON dde.key = fe.datekey
     JOIN dim_systeminterface ds ON ds.key = fe.systeminterfacekey
  WHERE fe.devicetype = 1
  GROUP BY df.tenantid, dd.region, dd.country, dd.state, dd.district, df.facilityname, ds.systemmanufacturer, dde.date, fe.licenseplatekey;
```

I do have an index on devicetype from the fe table. But it is never being used?

Comment: What indexes did you create for your tables? could you show us?

Comment: "Rows Removed by Filter: ~663,927", and that is just one table partition. Looks like your indexes don't match the conditions in the query, but we have no idea how the indexes are created.

Comment: I would expect a single index on devicetype, licenseplatekey , datekey, systeminterfacekey, facilitykey. Maybe a different order works better, that's what you can test.

Comment: Your plan seems to be truncated.  Where are the scans of ds and dde?

Comment: The plan shows under 7 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from caching more data in RAM or getting faster disks, a nested loop join *may* perform better:

```
CREATE INDEX ON fact_entriesexits (licenseplatekey, devicetype)
   INCLUDE (facilitykey, datekey, systeminterfacekey);

VACUUM fact_entriesexits;
```

That could get you an index-only scan.

Comment: But with a better index, it might not need to read half the rows.  With an index leading with (devicetype, licenseplatekey) it could read only 9% of the rows, which could at least plausibly be better (especially if enough of the rest of the columns were included to get a index-only-scan).

Comment: @jjanes Yes, that is true. A nested loop join *might* win.